# How can i disable in a Xcode project that a keyboard appears when i touch in a TextField?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Im a bit new in creating a xcode projects, so i have a program that i need to press the TextField to insert some values, but I don't want to do that with the native keyboard but only with the buttons that I will create, like a calculator.

**I already explore some definitions and i cant find the option!**

So I would like to know how can disable this option to the keyboard appears!

Comment: Check `inputView` property of `UITextField`.

Comment: @Desdenova I just check the property/atribute inspector and I find many types of keyboard inclusive only numbers! thanks for answer was a good help!

Comment: I meant read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this function in your viewController.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
     return NO; //hide keyboard
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Swift, try putting this in your view controller:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If all you want to do is disable the keyboard from appearing when you select the text field, you can set it's `editable` property to false. This however will prevent the user from editing the text field unless you update it programatically.

If all you are looking for is a number keyboard, you can set the `keyboardType` property to `UIKeyboardType.NumberPad`

If you want to make your own custom keyboard, you have two main options:

One option is to use a custom input view. There is a property on `UITextField` called `inputView` that lets you specify a custom view to be used instead of a keyboard. This only works if you want to display the view from the bottom like the keyboard.

If you want more flexibility in how the view is displayed, another option is to put a button over the text field so the actual text field cannot be selected. When the user taps the button, display whatever keys you want to display, and programmatically insert whatever text you want into the text field.

Comment: but i want to select the textfield to write!

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues I updated my answer with another option. But the original option still makes it appear as if you have selected the textfield to write. There just happens to be a transparent button over it.

Comment: I don't understand why this has downvotes it seems like a correct answer to what has been asked +1