# how to make keyboard not visible for UItextfield

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield

We have a requirement where we have created a numberpad on screen and want user to only use that numberpad to enter the value in Textfield.
Now, but when user comes onto that page, keyboard comes up by default. I wanna change some setting so that keyboard doesn't show up on that page.

Is there any way we can do this?

Comment: keybaord doesnt come up by default. It comes up when a textfield/text view has become first responder.

Comment: look at your code and remove the line, where it says become first responder!!!!

Comment: If i don't use become first responder, then curser wouldn't be in the textfield. User has to take the cursor themselves in textfield which is not a good user experience

Comment: You can make the textfield become first responder, when you tap on it.

Comment: ohh...so you want the textfield to become first responder, and you dont want to show the keyboard to user ?

Comment: yes.. this is causing main problem

Comment: try adding a uiview to the window which covers the keyboard, if that didnt worked out...make your own keypad!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i disable in a Xcode project that a keyboard appears when i touch in a TextField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998569/how-can-i-disable-in-a-xcode-project-that-a-keyboard-appears-when-i-touch-in-a-t)

Comment: If your never going to use a the keyboard, why not use a UILabel to display the text and a touch gesture recognizer to detect when the UILabel is touched to show your custom numberpad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set numberpad's `View` as `UITextField.inputView`.

See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html) doc.

Comment: We have customized numberpad on the screen and UItextfield. Not using this one. So, app doesn't need the default keyboard which comes up when curser is set in UItextfield

Comment: Why you need a UITextField then? Use UILabel.

Comment: Lot of validation need to happen when user enter data like decimal point, $ sign, number of character.. Using Textfield delegate method for those validation

Comment: Set `UITextField.enabled` to `NO`.

Comment: If i use UItextField.enabled = No, then text field will not be editable. I need text field should be editable, values in textfield should go from a custom Numberpad and iPad default keyboard should not come up.

Comment: How you add values from custom Numberpad to UITextField? If it is done programmatically, than it can be done with disabled UITextField as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for idea of using UIlabel instead of UItextfield. i changed the implementation and everything looks fine